# How to show the profile of the single user after user login?

Tags: php, html

I'm beginner in `PHP` and I have problem to fetch user profile (firstname, lastname, email, etc.) from database after they login. I'm already use `SELECT` query but for some reason it appear error below.

> Undefined index: id on line 52.

Here is the code below:

```
<?php
    session_start(); 
    include("config.php");
    if($_SESSION['login']!==true){
        header('location:login.php');
    }
?>

<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <title>Dashboard - Club Membership Management System</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

  </head>

  <body>

    <header>
      <div class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark box-shadow">
        <div class="container d-flex justify-content-between">
          <a href="#" class="navbar-brand d-flex align-items-center">
            <strong>Hi, <?php echo $_SESSION['type']?></strong>
          </a>
            <div class="pull-right">
                <?php
                if(isset($_POST['logout'])){
                    session_destroy();
                    header('location:user-home.php');
                }
    
                ?>
                <form method="post">
                    <button name="logout" class="btn btn-danger my-2">Logout</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </header>

    <main role="main">

      <section class="jumbotron text-center">
        <?php
          $id = $_GET['id']; //Here is the error
          $query = "select * from `accounts` where `id` = '$id'; ";
          if(count(fetchAll($query))>0) {
            foreach(fetchAll($query) as $row) {
              $firstname = $row['firstname'];
              $lastname = $row['lastname'];
              $email = $row['email'];
              $type = $row['type'];
              $picture = $row['picture'];
              $receipt = $row['receipt-pic'];
          ?> 
        <div class="container">
            <form method="POST">
              <label for="inputEmail">Firstname</label>
              <input name="firstname" type="text" id="inputEmail" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $row['firstname']?>" disabled><br>

              <label for="inputEmail">Lastname</label>
              <input name="lastname" type="text" id="inputEmail" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $row['lastname']?>" disabled><br>

              <label for="inputEmail">Email address</label>
              <input name="email" type="email" id="inputEmail" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $row['email']?>" disabled><br>

              <label for="inputType">Type</label>
              <input name="type" type="text" id="inputType" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $row['type']?>" disabled><br>

              <label for="inputPicture">Profile Photo</label>
              <input name=picture id="inputPicture" type="image" class="form-control" src="../uploads/<?php echo $row['picture'];?>" width="20%"><br>

              <label for="inputReceipt">Payment Receipt</label>
              <input name="receipt" type="image" id="inputReceipt" class="form-control" src="../uploads/<?php echo $row['receipt-pic'];?>" width="20%"><br> 
            </form>        
        </div>

        <?php 
            }
          }      
        ?>
          
      </section>

    </main>

    <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
    ================================================== -->
    <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here is the structure of accounts table:

```
-- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version 5.0.3
-- https://www.phpmyadmin.net/
--
-- Host: 127.0.0.1
-- Generation Time: Jan 02, 2021 at 09:33 AM
-- Server version: 10.4.14-MariaDB
-- PHP Version: 7.4.11

SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
START TRANSACTION;
SET time_zone = "+00:00";


/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8mb4 */;

--
-- Database: `clubsystem`
--

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `accounts`
--

CREATE TABLE `accounts` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `firstname` text NOT NULL,
  `lastname` text NOT NULL,
  `email` text NOT NULL,
  `type` text NOT NULL,
  `password` text NOT NULL,
  `picture` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `receipt-pic` varchar(250) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

--
-- Dumping data for table `accounts`
--

INSERT INTO `accounts` (`id`, `firstname`, `lastname`, `email`, `type`, `password`, `picture`, `receipt-pic`) VALUES
(1, 'Ahmad', 'Fauzi', 'ahmadfauzi@mtd.com', 'admin', 'fauzi', '', ''),
(6, 'Mohd', 'Termizi', 'mohdtermizie26@gmail.com', 'user', '1234', '', ''),
(7, 'Han ', 'Ji Pyeong', 'hjp@mtd.com', 'user', 'hjp', '', ''),
(8, 'Firdaus', 'Sabran', 'firdaussabran@mtd.com', 'user', 'firdaussabran', '', ''),
(9, 'Firdaus', 'Sabran', 'firdaussabran@mtd.com', 'user', 'firdaussabran', '', ''),
(10, 'Fisya', 'Medina', 'fisyamedina@mtd.com', 'user', 'fisyamedina', '', ''),
(11, 'Al', 'hafiz', 'alhafiz@mtd.com', 'user', 'alhafiz', '', ''),
(12, 'Siti', 'Iks', 'sitiiks@mtd.com', 'user', 'sitiiks', '', '');

--
-- Indexes for dumped tables
--

--
-- Indexes for table `accounts`
--
ALTER TABLE `accounts`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for dumped tables
--

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for table `accounts`
--
ALTER TABLE `accounts`
  MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=13;
COMMIT;

/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
```

.........................................................................................................

Comment: Hi, first of all dont use variables sent by user in sql statements. use prepared statements for it. Then you fetch two times the same query. Just execute once and save it in a variable. Also we dont know your "fetchAll" function. And now... your error is, because it seems your missing the get parameter in the url. Check if url.php?get={id} isset.

Comment: Pardon typo:  url.php?id={id} isset.

Comment: $_SESSION['login'] = true;
                        $_SESSION['type'] = $row['type'];
                        if ($_SESSION['type'] == 'admin') {
                          header('location:admin-home.php'); 
                        }
                        else {
                          header('location:user-home.php');  //How to change this to url.php?id.. as i'm using header

Comment: where do you have the userid stored of the target profile?

Comment: I'm stored it in table accounts

Comment: is it same url.php?id={id} isset with <a href=".php?id=<?php echo $row['id'] ?>">

Comment: nah. you want to open the profile of the loggedin user? then you have to store somewhere the info, which user is logged in, like id stored in $_SESSION

Comment: All calls to `header(...)` _must_ be made _before_ any output us made (which includes your HTML), so your `if (isset($_POST['logout'])) {`-check should be in the top, after the login-check but before you start outputting your html. In a request and response, all headers are sent first, before the content, so when you start outputting any content, it will automatically send the headers you've already defined, so if you set some header after that, then the headers have already been sent and your new header (like the redirect) won't be sent.

Answer (score 0):

I am going to give you an example:

Suppose you have a login form called login.php:

```
<html>
<body>
<form method="POST" action="tryLogin.php">
<label>Email:
<input type="email" name="email">
</label>
<br>
<label>Password:
<input type="password" name="password">
</label><br>

<input type="submit" value="Login">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

The file that will take the email and password and check if they exist in the database called: tryLogin.php:

```
       <?php
        session_start();//important
        $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","password","dbname");
        $email=$_POST["email"];
        $password=$_POST["password"];
        $checkEmailAndPassword="SELECT count(*) from users where email='$email' and password='$password'";
        $res=mysqli_query($con,$checkEmailAndPassowrd);
        $row=mysqli_fetch_array($res);
        if($row[0]==1){//here if $row[0] is 1 that means the user with that email and password is found
        $_SESSION["email"]=$email;//I saved the email in the session to fetch in the home page and get the user's information
        header("Location:home.php");
        }else {//user not found
        header("Location:login.php");
        }
        mysqli_close($con);
        ?>
```

The homepage called home.php:

```
<?php
session_start();//important

$email=$_SESSION["email"];
$getInfo="SELECT * from users where email='$email'";
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","username","password","dbname");
$res=mysqli_query($con,$getInfo);
$row=mysqli_fetch_array($res);
mysqli_close($con);
?>

<html>
<body>
<label>Email
<input type="email" value="<?php echo $row['email']; ?>">
</label>
<label>Firstname
<input type="text" value="<?php echo $row['firstname']; ?>">
</label>
</body>
</html
```

> 

Warning: Writing a code like this makes you wide open for sql injections, but since you are a beginner in php i gave you a simple solution.